# How to get the first line of a file in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have to put in a bash variable the first line of a file. I guess it is with the grep command, but it is any way to restrict the number of lines?

Answer (score 580, accepted):

`head` takes the first lines from a file, and the `-n` parameter can be used to specify how many lines should be extracted:

```
line=$(head -n 1 filename)
```

Comment: Significantly more overhead than the `read` approach. `$()` forks off a subshell, and using an external command (*any* external command) means you're calling `execve()`, invoking the linker and loader (if it's using shared libraries, which is usually the case), etc.

Comment: It could be even shorter: `line="$(head -1 FILENAME)"`

Comment: And also:
`line=\`head -1 FILENAME\``

Comment: Does the backticks around the `head...` open a subshell as `$()` does?.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel Yes, they're the same thing, though I personally find that the `$()` syntax is easier to see, and value clarity over absolute terseness. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Comment: This is the best answer because `head` is a POSIX standard utility.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ, true, but then again, `read` is a [POSIX command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), and it is implemented internally in `sh`, `dash` (often a lightweight shell), and `bash`, so it is fairly universal as well. What makes `head` being a POSIX standard utility the reason to choose an external command over an in-shell function.

Comment: can I use $filename , I hope it Is a variable

Comment: Additionally head is an external command and read is an internal builtin command so obviously read is quicker

Answer (score 96):

to read first line using bash, use `read` statement. eg

```
read -r firstline<file
```

`firstline` will be your variable (No need to assign to another)

Comment: @sorin, `cat ... | read VAR` will fail in most shells (all except `zsh` as far as I know) because each of the components in a pipe will run in separate subshells. Meaning that `$VAR` will be set in subshell (that cease to exist as soon as the pipeline has finished executing) rather than in the invoking shell. You can get around this with `read VAR <<EOF\n$(cat ...)\nEOF` (where each `\n` is a newline).

Comment: @sorin, `cat` is pure overhead; much more efficient to `read -r var <file` than `cat file | read` anyhow, even **if** the latter didn't fail for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: ...if you're running something more involved than `cat`, then `read -r var < <(otherprog ...)`

Comment: if you are using '<' in your file, this will fail with 'syntax error near unexpected token `newline'' see here: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/linux/bash-solve-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-newline/

Comment: In terms of performance, using read is better than head or any other commands like awk,sed.This is due to the fact that read is a internal command

Answer (score 44):

This suffices and stores the first line of `filename` in the variable `$line`:

```
read -r line < filename
```

I also like `awk` for this:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}' file
```

To store the line itself, use the `var=$(command)` syntax. In this case, `line=$(awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}' file)`.

Or even `sed`:

```
sed -n '1p' file
```

With the equivalent `line=$(sed -n '1p' file)`.

---

See a sample when we feed the `read` with `seq 10`, that is, a sequence of numbers from 1 to 10:

```
$ read -r line < <(seq 10) 
$ echo "$line"
1

$ line=$(awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}' <(seq 10))
$ echo "$line"
1
```

Comment: `sed '1!d;q'` (or `sed -n '1p;q'`) will mimic your `awk` logic and prevent reading further into the file.  Because we only want the first line, we can alternatively cheat with `sed q` or `awk '1;{exit}'` or even `grep -m1 ^` (less code, same essential logic).  (This is not a reply to the downvote inquiry.)

Comment: @AdamKatz that's a very nice set of ways, thanks! I find the one with `grep` very smart. We can of course also say `head -n 1 file`.

Comment: Yes, `head -n1` will be faster (smaller binary to load) and `read` will be fastest (no binary to load, that's a builtin).  I especially like `grep -m1 --color .` when I'm just printing the first line because it'll color the line too, making it great for table headings.

Answer (score 17):

Just `echo` the first list of your source file into your target file.

```
echo $(head -n 1 source.txt) > target.txt
```

Comment: For which `head -n 1 source.txt > target.txt` will accomplish exactly the same.

Answer (score 16):

```
line=$(head -1 file)
```

Will work fine. (As previous answer). But

```
line=$(read -r FIRSTLINE < filename)
```

will be marginally faster as `read` is a built-in bash command.

Comment: Second method doesn't work as written, because `read` doesn't print anything (so `line` winds up blank), and also executes in a subshell (so `FIRSTLINE` gets set to the first line, but only in the subshell, so it's not available afterward).  Solution: just use `read -r line <filename`

Comment: line=$(read -r < filename ;printf %s  "$REPLY") should work
or alternatively 
    line=$(read -r < <(some command); printf %s "$REPLY")

Answer (score 6):

The question didn't ask which is fastest, but to add to the sed answer, -n '1p' is badly performing as the pattern space is still scanned on large files. Out of curiosity I found that 'head' wins over sed narrowly:

```
# best:
head -n1 $bigfile >/dev/null

# a bit slower than head (I saw about 10% difference):
sed '1q' $bigfile >/dev/null

# VERY slow:
sed -n '1p' $bigfile >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get any line you want with the following syntax:

```
n=4;
line=$(head -n $n file | tail -n 1)
```

The way this works is first of all the `head -n $n` file lists all `n` lines in the file and we pass the output of the head command to the `tail` command which will extract the last line