# Processing log files using bash tools

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

I have a .csv file with approx 10 columns that is logging data.  I want to use something like this:

[How to get the first line of a file in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439579/how-to-get-the-first-line-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script)

Where it is grabbing the first line of each file and then processing the logs.  However, once the line is processed, I want to mark it as processed (can be as simple as adding a new column on the end with a *** or something).  So basically, I want to grab the first line not processed, process it, and move to the next unprocessed line, etc.

I need to do this using sed, awk, grep, and/or other standards.  The bash script will sit and run in the background on an infinite while loop.  Essentially, I am trying to read and process this log file in real-time, but need the log for history.

**Edit:**
Also, I need this to mark the lines that have been read in the file.  That way if the server stops, I can know right where to pick up processing.  So tail will work if I can figure out a way to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: So you don't want the first line in the file, but rather the first unprocessed line?

Comment: Correct - I do want the first unprocessed line.  Logrotate is a possibility ... but like the original post said this will be running and I need to grab this data as close to real-time as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than sitting in a infinite loop you could do this:

```
tail -n +1 -f your_log_file | some_processing_pipeline
```

This will start reading your logfile at line 1, then continuously wait for new lines to appear and pass them to `some_processing_pipeline`.

Comment: Is there a way to have that line get marked once it gets passed?  In case of system catastrophe (or simple error somewhere) I need to have the line mark itself as processed.  Otherwise, that solution sounds great.

Comment: Maybe in that case you want to create a new log file, like [Lev Levitsky suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038896/processing-log-files-using-bash-tools/12039101#comment16070919_12038896). I'm not sure it's wise to edit a log file after it has been created.

Comment: Big question to creating a new file is if something happens and the log processing stops, and I need to start it again, how do I know where to start?

Comment: You could tell your processor that if something happens to move the log else where and start a new one. But that might not be as easy or sensible as it sounds.

Comment: Right ... and in the case of server failure, patching reboot, etc ... that might not always be practical.  Thus, the reason I was looking for some way to just mark the line as processed.  There isn't a way to piggy-back a sed command onto that?

Comment: Then surely the process creating the log will die at the same time?

Comment: Mostly.  But there is concern that if the process doing the reading stops, we need a fail-safe way to ensure those records were read.

Comment: @fophillips : The lines from the log file will not be processed as soon as they appear, the pipe will wait to be filled and then dump (8k?) buffer full of data to processing pipeline.  In this case though that should not be a problem.

Comment: Sorry - not meaning to argue.  But what happens if the server gets rebooted, and the process starts.  It will start at the bottom of the file and re-process all over again.  I need some way to maintain a state of these ....

Comment: Maybe have your analysis keep a log of its own?