# How to monitor JVM and know whether it is a minor GC or major GC for Parallel GC in real time way?

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

Oracle provides some [tools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr025.html) for monitoring.

But I cannot use visual tools since I am using a terminal. 
Also, [jstat utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html) cannot tell whether it is a minor GC or major GC when I use Parallel GC.

Is there any interface that I can detect whether it is a minor GC or major GC when JVM performs a Parallel GC?

Comment: Why do you need to know in *which type of GC cycle* the JVM is *while it is happening*?

Comment: Use JMX notifications on GarbageCollectorMXBean.

Comment: @the8472 I think major GC is longer than minor GC. It is worth observing.

Comment: @apangin I cannot change Java code. JMX should be added into the code. But I can't.

Comment: @skytree Not necessary. You can start JMX agent using JVM options and then connect to the server [remotely](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html).

Comment: Thanks, but like @Alex M981 mentioned, `If you want to know when a GC starts or is in the middle of one you probably will need additional logging since most of the information is only written out once a GC cycle has finished.` I check that minor gc and major gc start don't have any log. Can JMX agent detect major or minor GC in PS GC though?

Comment: but why do you need to observe the fact that it is a major vs. minor GC *while it is happening* instead of after the fact? such a thing is not possible inside java because all java execution is blocked while the GC runs. it would require some native code.

Comment: @the8472  Purpose: debugging and testing performance. I agree it is impossible inside java program code. It doesn't matter how we get these info.

Comment: then record the information and correlate the data later, from what you have said there appears no need to record GC events in the middle of them.

Answer (score -1):

you should add JVM options to log GC activities of your JVN process:

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/your/log/dir/gc.log
```

check out the article about [understanding the format of GC log](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-garbage-collection-log)

Here is a [list of GC log analysis tools](http://fasterj.com/tools/gcloganalysers.shtml). Maybe some of these tools will help you.

In order to monitor number of minor/major GC you can use [jstat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html) . Example:

```
jstat -gcutil 21891 250 7
  S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
  0.00  97.02  70.31  66.80  95.52  89.14      7    0.300     0    0.000    0.300
  0.00  97.02  86.23  66.80  95.52  89.14      7    0.300     0    0.000    0.300
  0.00  97.02  96.53  66.80  95.52  89.14      7    0.300     0    0.000    0.300
 91.03   0.00   1.98  68.19  95.89  91.24      8    0.378     0    0.000    0.378
 91.03   0.00  15.82  68.19  95.89  91.24      8    0.378     0    0.000    0.378
 91.03   0.00  17.80  68.19  95.89  91.24      8    0.378     0    0.000    0.378
 91.03   0.00  17.80  68.19  95.89  91.24      8    0.378     0    0.000    0.378
```

You should pay attention on `YGC` and `FGC` columns. Here is an article explaining [Minor GC vs Major GC vs Full GC](https://plumbr.io/blog/garbage-collection/minor-gc-vs-major-gc-vs-full-gc)

Comment: But how to do it in a real time way? I know log but it can only be processed afterwards.

Comment: Is there any way to do in bash file for parsing the log stream?

Comment: maybe jstat might help you. It can show counts of young generation GC events as well and other stats.

Comment: "vague" means I need to know the state that jvm is during minor / major GC, it should indicate me the start and end of the status.

Comment: in this case raw logs might be better. The common approach is outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038896/processing-log-files-using-bash-tools . If you need enterprise scale you might use tools like splunk for aggregating logs and then querying through them.

Comment: It seems to be possible to parse raw log in real time but I still don't know how....

Comment: you might try awk parsing language. You can find lots of examples of parsing various logs using awk just by googling

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Let me try first.

Comment: If you want to know when a GC starts or is in the middle of one you probably will need additional logging since most of the information is only written out once a GC cycle has finished.