# Bash script to check line on website

Tags: bash, curl, request

I'm pretty new to bash, I wanted to access a url with a bash and save the first line from the url in a text file

I can access the url via curl command

```
curl -IS http://url.com:8090
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first line of a file in a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439579/how-to-get-the-first-line-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
YOURVAR=`curl -IS http://url.com:8090 | awk 'NR==1'`
echo $YOURVAR
```

Comment: is there a way to save it as string instead of a text?

Comment: You mean as a variable?  Changed response to use variable