# Shell script how to create a right declaration in Android

Tags: android, if-statement, sh

i don't know what the right title for this question but i have a problem like this:

i have a file inside `a` folder, the name is `test.txt` and have a value `6`
i open the terminal and use `su` command to get root access (just in case), then i try this script

```
tek="/a/test.txt"
if [ "$tek" -le "8" ]; then
  echo " 6 <= 8 "
else
  echo "nice"
fi
```

and there is an error `sush: /a/test.txt: unexpected '/' tmn`
i try another way like this `tek="a/test.txt"` and i get an error `sush: a/test.txt: zero divisor tmn`
can someone tell me what is wrong with my script?

i do this all in Android device

if there is someone know what is the right title for this question please change it, i'll be so grateful

Comment: what happens if you type `echo $SHELL` on the cmd-line? (Hard to know what to write for your title yet ;-) ) ... Good luck.

Comment: i don't know where to put the `echo $SHELL`, so the problem is the error, maybe my declaration is wrong, missing, or something like that

Comment: I should have mentioned that "maybe we can help diagnose your problem if we know " what response you get when  you type `echo $SHELL` on your command-line. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the first line, you have to call `$(head -n 1 a/test.txt)`, not just reference the file path, so try this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

tek=$(head -n 1 a/test.txt)
if [ "$tek" -le "8" ]; then
        echo "6 <= 8"
else
        echo "nice"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @qudproquo it works. If you can, please explain me what is the function of `$` in `tek=$(head -n 1 /a/test.txt)`? I need to know every function and command so i can develop it

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439579/how-to-get-the-first-line-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script