# Rename a single file using the first line in a .txt file

Tags: bash, text-files

Currently I have two files, in this instance lets call them example1.txt and example2.txt

How do I go about renaming example2.txt to the first line inside the example1.txt file? The first line in this file will always be a version number i.e. 7.16.5.5, and shouldn't contain any spaces.

Cheers!

Comment: Please insert the code that you tried and then we will help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439579/how-to-get-the-first-line-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script then `mv example2.txt $line`

Comment: hey, if any of the following answers helped you than please accept/upvote the answer for closure.

Answer (score 3):

```
mv example2.txt "$(head -1 example1.txt)"
```

Anyting insde `$()` would be subprocess and executed first. So above command translate to :

```
mv example2.txt 7.16.5.5
```

To preserve the `txt` extension :

```
mv example2.txt "$(head -1 example1.txt).txt"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Is there a way to add the .txt extension back on? When I rename the file the .txt extension is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Or, by filtering, e.g. from a file like:

```
this is the version 1.2.3.4
bla

mv example2.txt "$(grep -m1 -oP '\d+(\.\d+)*' example1.txt).txt"
```

Comment: This would be a fine answer to a *completely different question from the one asked*.

Comment: @slim it works for his question too..., e.g. if the file contains alone version number in the 1st line. just it is a bit more universal..

Comment: He asked for file2 to be renamed using the first line of file1.  Yours renames file1 using the first line in file1 that matches a pattern you've invented (that happens to match his example).

Comment: @slim ah, youre right! Thanx. changed.  Sometimes is good to read the whole question ... :) :)